# alternative for ftp to backup all my server files?

Tags: ftp, filezilla, web-hosting

I am trying to download all my files from my old server (a free web hosting) to upload on a new server.
The problem is, for some reason, when I am using ftp to download all my files, many files are missing and do not get downloaded (I am using File Zilla), some are listen in 'failed transfer', but the rest are not.
I keep trying to download the missing stuff, but there are so many files to check.
The server has a file limit of 10 MB, so I can't zip the files and download them.
Is there a way I can download all of my files without losing any ?

Comment: Do you have shell access?

Comment: @gronostaj sadly I don't. (I regret putting time and effort in a free hosting)

Comment: So maybe some scripting language? PHP?

Comment: Did try a different FTP client?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I haven't tried since everyone said File Zilla was the best you could get. But I guess I probably should try.

Comment: doesnt your hosting offer a backup and download function?  is it a cPanel based host?

Answer (score 0):

The safest way to assure that your download is complete, is to zip your folders,
download the zip archive, and unpack it on the target computer.

You will then know that nothing is missing, on condition that the zip archive
has been downloaded and unpacked successfully.